# Model design for account referrals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating a system where users can refer other users and in turn receive benefits. I currently have a User model created via Devise for authentication.

Just wondering what is the best way to create the referral model?

So far I have something like this as my table:

id  user_id   referrer_id

However, by default referred_id will infer a model called referrer. Anyway to automate the creation of referrals? Also just wondering how others have implemented this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to store the referring user there's probably no need for another model. Just associate with another User object:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :referrer, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Just be sure to add a `referrer_id` column to your `users` table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also have another field named "approved". Hence I wanted to separate out the extra data into its own model. Do you think this is wise? Or simply add another column?

Comment: I think it depends on whether you plan to add more functionality in the future. If I were in the early stages of development and moving quickly I'd just add a `referrer_approved` boolean column to my `users` table. Even though this is not the most elegant solution, strictly speaking, if it saves time and isn't a central part of the application (doesn't sound like it is) then it may be the more practical solution. If referrals become more important in the future you could add a `Referrer` model with columns like `referring_user_id`, `referred_user_id`, and whatever else you want.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need an entire model - just a many-to-1 relationship. Add a column to the Users class called "referred_by_user_id" and then add the following to your User model.

```
belongs_to :referred_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "referred_by_user_id"

has_many :referrals, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "referred_by_user_id"
```